# CRM 2011: Plugin to update Incident on new activity added

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a requirement to create a Task when a new activity as added to an Incident (Case). I Think can be achieved by triggering a workflow on Activity Creating and check the regarding field. If regarding entity is a Case then run a custom workflow activity to create task.

I think running workflow on each activity creating might be bit overkill. Is there any way to create a plugin to trigger on activity added to Case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create plugin that will be triggered after activity is created. But you will have to validate that activity was created related to case in the body of the plugin.